# What is SafeFileHandle in C# and when should I use it?

Tags: c#, safefilehandle

While I am still learning System.IO, in `File` `Stream` class 's constructors, I found that there are overloaded constructors with the type named `SafeFileHandle`, I tried to search on the internet and the MSDN Documention, but I can't understand anything, and I found **even** **stranger** words, like `IntPtr`, can any one explain it to me?

```
public FileStream (Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle handle, System.IO.FileAccess access, int bufferSize, bool isAsync);
```

can someone explain it, or are there good websites that I can learn from..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle?view=netframework-4.8

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/Microsoft/Win32/SafeHandles/SafeFileHandle@cs/1/SafeFileHandle@cs

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/SafeFileHandle/-/php-safefilehandle-class-examples.html

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwizlPG3ornlAhVFCKwKHUl9DxIQFjABegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fmicrosoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.-ctor&usg=AOvVaw3M0YPCVH1439KghalbcDfG

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.safefilehandle?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

These links provide info on `SafeFileHandle`, and some provide source code.

You can also check this out: [How to Close SafeFile Handle properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827222/how-to-close-safefile-handle-properly)

`IntPtr`...

It's a "native (platform-specific) size integer." It's internally represented as void* but exposed as an integer. You can use it whenever you need to store an unmanaged pointer and don't want to use unsafe code. IntPtr.Zero is effectively NULL (a null pointer).

`Pointer`...

In general (across programming languages), a pointer is a number that represents a physical location in memory. A null pointer is (almost always) one that points to 0, and is widely recognized as "not pointing to anything". Since systems have different amounts of supported memory, it doesn't always take the same number of bytes to hold that number, so we call a "native size integer" one that can hold a pointer on any particular system.

`SafeFileHandle` `kernel32`...

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
  uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
  uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

More with `SafeFileHandle` and `kernel32`...

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
string lpFileName,
uint dwDesiredAccess,
uint dwShareMode,
IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
uint dwCreationDisposition,
uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
IntPtr hTemplateFile);
private SafeFileHandle handleValue = null;
handleValue = CreateFile(
Path,
GENERIC_WRITE,
0,
IntPtr.Zero,
OPEN_EXISTING,
0,
IntPtr.Zero);
```

Though, if you are trying to open a `File`, then use the `System.IO` `Controls`

To simply open a file and read all of it's text:

`richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(yourfilename);`

You can change the `richTextBox1` to your `Control`'s name.

I hope I am helping you, Prof Soft :)

Comment: ohh thanks broo , but i already opened this links when i was searching and i cant understand , if you know what is safe file handle IntPtr can you explain it to me by your style probably i understand from you broo :)

Comment: I updated my answer with more links :) I don't have as much experience with `SafeFileHandle`

Comment: ohh I do not know what to say thank you for caring , i am waiting you :)

Comment: Once again, I updated my answer(With as much detail as I could do at the moment)

Comment: If you need more info, just ask :)

Comment: Okay, Prof Soft, I added another snippet of code to my answer :)

Comment: - **Technically, I forgot to mention the** `using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles`, **or that you need to add the** `Assembly Reference` `Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles` **- Sorry :D**

Comment: heyy broo ,how are you :) , haha thanks very much for your caring , i cant find any words to thank you , [ THANKS VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY MUCH ] @Momoro

Comment: It's really no problem :)

Comment: This really helped! Thanks!

Comment: @IamCode - No Problem!