# Are there any benefits for using SafeFileHandle with FileStream constructor

Tags: c#, handle, safefilehandle

I read a lot about `SafeFileHandle` and from what I've seen I think I don't have to use it or it doesn't have any benefits to use it in `FileStream` because it is closed by first object of file stream handled it and I can't use it in another objects.

Can any one tell me when should I use it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string path = "Hello";

    SafeFileHandle handle = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate).SafeFileHandle;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        // do work
    }
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

From what I have seen that definition of `SafeFileHandle` is: it is something like a person hold one hand of a rope and they are playing with children, and every child hold the second hand of rope.

person = file handle or any handle (network connection or anything)

rope = `SafeFileHandle`

kids = objects that want to make operations with file handle like `FileStream`

This is my perception about safe file handle, is it correct?

Comment: The point of the `SafeFileHandle` is to use with native unmanaged code like the [`CreateFile`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile) method. Unless you have a very good reason to use it, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed okay broo but can you tell me what is a native unmanaged code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overloads that accept `SafeFileHandle` exist for the same reason that the now-obsolete overloads that accepted an `IntPtr` did: so that you can construct a new `FileStream` instance from a file handle that you obtained through p/invoke interop, i.e. from unmanaged code.

The `SafeHandle` type and idiom for its use did not exist in the earliest versions of .NET. Raw `IntPtr` values were used any time managed code needed to deal with native handles. When the much better `SafeHandle` type was introduced, it simply made sense to provide specific subclasses for commonly-used native handle types, like file handles, and then to support those specific subclasses in any managed API, including constructors like those for `FileStream`, where the native handle type previously was used.

The example you've provided would never (or at least, should never) appear in real-world code. If you are opening a file from managed code and using it only in managed code, then you just do that. You never have any reason to mess with the native file handle at all. You would use the `SafeFileHandle` property of a `FileStream` object only if you needed to pass the native file handle to unmanaged code, and you would pass a `SafeFileHandle` value to the `FileStream` constructor only if you had no way to obtain that particular file handle except from unmanaged code.

Frankly, I don't really understand your analogy with the rope and children. It doesn't seem correct or useful to me though. You already got an answer to your previous, very broad question [What is SafeFileHandle in c# and when should i use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58568415), so you should already know why `SafeFileHandle` exists, but to recap here:

- `SafeHandle`, and its subclasses, are provided as a much-better alternative to having to make one's class deal with finalizers. The `SafeHandle` class itself implements the finalization logic, so your class doesn't have do. At least, as long as the only unmanaged objects your class would normally deal with can be wrapped in a `SafeHandle` subclass — and since you can implement your own wrappers, for those objects that don't already have a .NET-provided wrapper, this should be *all* of your unmanaged objects — then you don't need a finalizer. (You still need to implement `IDisposable`, so that your unmanaged objects can be cleaned up deterministically…the finalizer is solely there as a backup).

I hope that the above is sufficient to explain all this. Stack Overflow isn't really the right place for extensive, tutorial level explanations of concepts. But, assuming the above short discussion provides the level of detail you needed to understand why those constructors exist, that seems fine to me.