# Using the new features SafeFileHandle for IO operations

Tags: c#

Can anybody help me with the new `SafeFileHandle` feature in .NET 6?

I tried [this article](https://blog.okyrylchuk.dev/20-new-apis-in-net-6#heading-reading-and-writing-files), but the output isn't merging; only a single file.

Here's my old code using `File.Create()` only:

```
public static async Task MergeFiles(string folderToMerge, string outputFilePath) 
{
    using var output = File.Create(outputFilePath);
    var files = folderToMerge.EnumerateFiles("mp4");
    foreach (var (i, file) in files.EnumerateWithIndex()) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Merging file {i + 1} of {files.Count()}");
        using var input = File.OpenRead(file);
        await input.CopyToAsync(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: improve your title, please

Comment: Have look this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568415/what-is-safefilehandle-in-c-sharp-and-when-should-i-use-it , the answer might help you.

Comment: @MoRe sorry I didn't notice it was incomplete